# Wrapping a C function with Cython, producing NaN

Tags: python, c, cython, wrapper, nan

I have a function in a `C` code that returns a `double`. 
In order to make a reproducible example, I will simplify it extremely in the following way. In the `.c` file:

```
double myfunction_at_k_and_z(struct background * pba,
                          struct spectra * psp,
                          struct perturbs *ppt,
                          double k,
                          double z,
                          double * pk_ic) 
{ 
double result = 3.;

return result;}
```

in the `.h` file:

```
double myfunction_at_k_and_z (struct background * pba,
                          struct spectra * psp,
                          struct perturbs *ppt,
                          double k,
                          double z,
                          double * pk_ic);
```

and everything works well with it, the output `result` is the one I am expecting, I can use e.g. `fprintf` inside the function to print the value of `result` on screen and it looks good.

Now I would like to wrap this function with a `Python` wrapper, using `Cython`. In the `.pyx` file I create this function within a class `myclass`:

```
def get_myfunction_at_k_and_z(self, double k, double z):
        cdef double dummy
        cdef double result = myfunction_at_k_and_z(&self.ba, &self.sp, &self.pt, k, z, &dummy)
        return result
```

and in the `.pxd` file I declare:

```
double myfunction_at_k_and_z (background * pba, spectra * psp, perturbs *ppt, double k, double z, double * pk_ic)
```

so that the wrapper knows about the original function in `C`. This compiles nicely, but if now I call `myfunction_at_k_and_z` from `Python`, at values e.g. `k = 0.1, z = 1.` via

```
myclass.get_myfunction_at_k_and_z(0.1,1.)
```

this function prints a `nan`!!!
That is odd, why does it work in `C` but not in `Python`?

Comment: Can you make this into a reproducible example, i.e. a [mcve]?  Thanks.

Comment: @TobySpeight I am editing my post

Comment: Can you share your `setup.py`? Also, how is the C code and the extension compiled? Specifically, what compiler is used for each and how is the linking performed?

Comment: This still isn't a complete and verifiable example. We're missing the declarations of `background`, `spectra`, `perturbs`, and also the class `myclass`. It's possible that the build information that danny mentioned in also relevant, but at a minimum we need some code that we can actually compile and see the error.